# How to make a symlink of a folder which would be viable on other partition?

Tags: macos

I have 2 partitions on my Mac - the first with Catalina and second with Big Sur.
I would have to make a link to a folder which is located on my desktop on Catalina, then move that link to Big Sur partition so that to have access to that folder when I'm on Big Sur, without going to Catalina partition. I created a symlink on Catalina, but after moving it to Big Sur a message popped-up about lack of source or something.

Is it feasible to open a folder located on other partition using symlinks?

Comment: Does an old-style Alias work? i don't have Catalina or Big Sur to test.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. The simplest solutions often are the better.

Comment: Symlink should work too. You should post the command you used to create the link, and how you moved it (Finder, Terminal, etc.). You could use iCloud too, although that’s wasting disk space on one partition.